# How do I fix and prevent EOSIO Node Instances from becoming unusable in EOS Studio

Tags: nodeos, eos-studio

Just learning EOS and using EOS studio.  Twice now my instances have become unusable.  As you can see in the image, there is no longer a start button or a version.  The gear/config button does nothing for these either.

When I first open the application, if I try and click the toggle for the network the application screen goes black and will no longer respond.  I am assuming because it trying to connect to my initial broken instance.

I started with the command line but NODEOS started showing dirty every time I tried to start it (even with --replay-blockchain)

Am I doing something wrong or is there something I can do to recover these instances or at least delete them?  I would like to avoid this happening in the future.

[image: Broken Instances]

[image: Unresponsive Application]

Answer (score 1):

try the telegram channel were the `eos studio` representatives are hanging out
https://t.me/blackide

or the `eos developers` telegram channel
https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1